# Аппаратное кэширование HDD (на чтение), скорость чтения

Tags: кэширование, hdd

Интересует алгоритм(ы). Кому режет глаз термин "кэширование" - читайте это как "дисковая буфферизация". Хотел бы услышать детально про **`Read-ahead/read-behind`**

Убедительная просьба - не отвечать концептуально! Обзорных статей я начитался. И вторая просьба - не обсуждать тут иные виды кэширования, как-то аппаратное RAID-контроллеров. А тем паче программное.

**Вопрос**

Интересует вшитая в контроллер логика и последовательность действий, которую аппаратура производит, дабы ускорить операции чтения.

Comment: На самом деле, если следовать одной из цитат Кнута -- ["Людям, которые действительно интересуются компьютерами, следует знать по крайней мере некоторые идеи о том, что представляет собой используемое ими «железо». Иначе, программы, которые они напишут, будут достаточно непонятными."](http://abv24.com/citaty-7-donald-knut), это весьма ценный вопрос.

Comment: @avp, *это весьма ценный вопрос* — данный вопрос, по-моему, не представляет никакой ценности для базы знаний. ценным мог бы быть **ответ** на него, но те, кто сможет дать аргументированный ответ, увы, «не ходят по всяким сайтикам в интернете».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ответы без вопроса (да еще на столь неожиданную тему) не появятся. Вот я бы с удовольствием почитал, чем отличается  firmware HP от firmware Hitachi  и Seagate  для в принципе одинаковых SAS HDD, предназначенных, например, для HP XP (или не отличается...).

Comment: @avp, *не появятся* — регулярно появляются. называются «статьи» и «книги». публикуются на тематических ресурсах. нередко — бумажных.

Comment: [Немного о диске "изнутри"](http://hddscan.com/doc/HDD_Tracks_and_Zones.html), обратите внимание, количество секторов на дорожках разное. Что касается кэширования, то насколько я понял в области дисков используют термин [disk buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) типичного размера 8-256 Мбит (по моим оценкам, совсем немного) в котором сохраняют сектора (по 512 байт (4 килобита)), которые проходят под головкой в процессе поиска запрошенного сектора.

Comment: @avp  прошивка hdd может содержать даже заплатки от NSA (то есть "детальное" описание тяжело найти). Интересная статья [Hard disk hacking](http://spritesmods.com/?art=hddhack). Ответы такого объёма (по количеству символов) за рамками Stack Overflow находятся.

Comment: @jfs, о, спасибо! Интересное чтиво. Почему-то вспомнилась стена в одной лаборатории, где я работал в середине 80-х, вся закленная микрофотографиями слоев вскрытого транспьютера.

Comment: @jfs, прочел. Нереально крутой хакинг. А по сути темы, согласен,  такие статьи это не ответ на вопросы ТС. Но, кто знает, может найдется желающий (и достаточно компетентный)  "переварить" их и сделать хороший ответ. (интересно, ТС, будучи под баном, получает  эти комментарии?)

Comment: Связанный ответ на Мете: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4396/208074